# kubectl run with env var from a secret config

Tags: kubernetes

How can I issue a `kubectl run` that pulls an environment var from a k8s secret configmap?

Currently I have:

`kubectl run oneoff -i --rm NAME --image=IMAGE --env SECRET=foo`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look into the `overrides` flag of the `run` command... it reads as:

> An inline JSON override for the generated object. If this is non-empty, it is used to override the generated object. Requires that the object supply a valid apiVersion field.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#run

So in your case I guess it would be something like:

```
kubectl run oneoff -i --rm --overrides='
{
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "oneoff",
        "image": "IMAGE",
        "env": [
          {
            "name": "ENV_NAME"
            "valueFrom": {
              "secretKeyRef": {
                "name": "SECRET_NAME",
                "key": "SECRET_KEY"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
'  --image= IMAGE
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that setting overrides for containers pretty much overrides everything, including `run` parameters such as image (which is mandatory to override) and command, for example. Just got bitten by that, `--command -- /my/custom/command` was being completely ignored, I had to set it inside the overrides.

Comment: As Bruno Medeiros says above, while default mode is called "merge", this overrides everything e.g. in containers (because it's a list). You might have more luck with `--override-type=strategic` (introduced in kubectl 1.23 if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 6):

This is another one that does the trick:

```
 kubectl run oneoff -i --rm NAME --image=IMAGE --env SECRET=$(kubectl get secret your-secret -o=jsonpath="{.server['secret\.yml']}")
```